# Error:[$controller:ctrlreg] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=js%2Fapp%2Fshop%2FShopController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this **Shop.js** script:

```
<pre>(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('ShopController', ShopController);
    ShopController.$inject = ['$http'];



    function ShopController($http) {
        var vm = this;
        $http.get('/shop/shirts')
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.responsedata = response.product;
            },function (reason) {
                console.log(reason);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }


}());
```

here is my html that uses Shopcontroller

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!--{{# each this}}-->
    <div ng-repeat= "rest in vm.responsedata">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
                <div class="productinfo text-center">
                    <img src="{{rest.imagePath}}" alt="" />
                    <h2>${{rest.price}}</h2>
                    <p>{{.title}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product-overlay" style="background-image: url({{this.imagePath2}});">
                    <div class="overlay-content">
                        <h2>${{this.price}}</h2>
                        <p>{{this.title}}</p>
                        <a href="/details/shirts/{{this.detailLink}}" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"></i>Show Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!--{{/each}}-->
</div>
```

and my route-config file is

```
<pre>
(function () {
'use strict';

    angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'js/app/index/index.html',
                controller :'RootController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            })
            .when('/users/create', {
                templateUrl : 'js/app/users/users.html',
                controller :'UserController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            })
            .when('/design', {
                templateUrl : 'js/app/design/design.html',
                controller :'DesignController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            })
            .when('/shop/shirts', {
                templateUrl : 'js/app/shop/shop.html',
                controller :'js/app/shop/ShopController',
                controllerAs : 'vm'
            });

    }
}());
```

And I am still getting error:

> Error:[$controller:ctrlreg]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=js%2Fapp%2Fshop%2FShopController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change controller to ShopController in route-config file.

```
  .when('/shop/shirts', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/app/shop/shop.html',
                    controller : 'ShopController',
                    controllerAs : 'vm'
                });
```

Comment: have you included file in index.html ?, can you post you index.html?
make sure to add script of controller file.

Comment: this error is still occurring in all controller in route-config

Comment: <script src="js/shopController.js"></script> - in your index.html

Comment: `<div ng-app="app"><br>
    <div ng-view></div><br>
</div>

<script src="/bower/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/bower/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app/route-config.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app/shop/shop.js"></script>`

Comment: this is my shop.hbs as I metioned above view in views folder

Answer (score 0):

you probably messed up brackets in your code file, make sure there is everything correct
Also next time open a web browser console (probably press F12) and see the output errors